# Read part of string to integer array

Tags: c++, arrays

I was writing a C++ program to manipulate a text file. A part of the task involves searching the text file for a particular "search string" and store a part of it as an  integer array.

I wrote the following code:

```
ifstream myoutfile;                      
myoutfile.open (outputfile.c_str());    // filename is passed as a user input
string search="SEARCH STRING"           // search string
while (getline(myoutfile, line))
{
     if (line.find(search) != string::npos)
     {
           cout << line[54] << line[55] << line[56] << endl;  
     }
}
```

the thing is I want to read 54th 55th and 56th characters of the line into an array as a single integer. (Lets say that 54th charcter is '1' 55th is '2' and 56th is '6'. I would like to read it as number 126 into an array. Is it possible to do that inside this loop, or
I have to save this into a file and write a separate section to read contents of the file into array. I was wondering whether anybody can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [std::string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to get sub-string out and convert to int. Also could use [std::atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)

```
#include <sstream>

int i = 0;
std::istringstream ss(line.substr(54, 3));
ss >> i;
```

Or

```
#include <cstdlib>
int b = std::atoi(line.substr(54, 3).c_str());
```

Comment: stringstream could convert that.

Comment: Much easier to use `std::stoi` (or `std::atoi` on old compilers).

Comment: You never want to use `atoi`, since you have no way of capturing any errors.  `std::istringstream` is a good solution if you don't have `std::stoi`; even if `std::stoi` is present, the `std::istringstream` solution may be preferable, as it avoids issues with exceptions.

Comment: And of course, with the `std::istringstream` solution, you have to verify its state, and that it has consumed all of the characters you've passed to it.

Comment: @JohnP what's your question?

Comment: @billz, I am sorry, in between typing I accidently hit enter key and  posted the message. I tried the std::stringstream, it worked well. I also wanted to understand the std::atoi part of the code that you provided. The code reads int b = std::atoi(s.substr(1,3).c_str()); I was wondering about the (1,3) part, what does it do?

Comment: @JohnP sorry, I updated my code. it should be `line.substr(54, 3)` which is the substring of line which should be "126" as you mentioned in your sample.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I worked the code out for both `std::stoi` and `std::istringstream`.  The version using `std::istringstream` is actually simpler, once error handling has been taken into account.  (If you've got a string extracted using a regular expression along the lines of `"\\d{3}"`, then of course `std::stoi` is the way to go.)

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks a lot for the inputs. I will go with std::stoi (or std::atoi), as it is short and simple. Thanks a lot everybody for replying.

Answer (score 3):

if it is just the 54 till 56 chars exactly you can do:

```
int x = (line[54] - '0') * 100 +(line[55] - '0') * 10 +(line[56] - '0') ;
```

the `line[54] - '0'` part convert the char sign number to the number it is.

Comment: Not until you've verified that they really are digits.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution here is `std::istringstream`, but it does
require more work than other posters seem to suggest:

```
std::istringstream parser( line.substr( 54, 3 ) );
parser >> i;
if ( !parser || parser.get() != EOF ) {
    //  Error.
} else {
    //  No error, you can use i...
}
```

If you have C++11, you can use `std::stoi`, but at first look,
it seems even more complex:

```
size_t end = 0;
try {
    i = std::stoi( line.substr( 54, 3 ), &end );
} catch ( std::runtime_error const& ) {
    //  No numeric characters present...
    //  end remains 0...
} 
if ( end != 3 ) {
    //  Error, either string wasn't long enough, or
    //  contained some non-numeric.
} else {
    //  No error, you can use i...
}
```

On the other hand, by catching `std::invalide_argument` and
`std::out_of_range` separately, you can distingish the type of
error.

Or, of course, you can just use `strtol` directly:

```
char tmp1[4] = {};
line.copy( tmp1, 3, 54 );
char* end;
errno = 0;
long tmp2 = strtol( tmp1, &end, 10 );
if ( errno != 0 || end != tmp1 + 3 || tmp2 > INT_MAX || tmp2 < INT_MIN ) {
    //  Error...
} else {
    i = tmp2;
    //  No error, you can use i...
}
```

All things considered, I think I prefer the first method (but
the last *will* probably be significantly faster).